# What is the difference between .html and .xhtml extension? XHTML is a markup language or it'a different extension also

Tags: html, xhtml, mime-types, doctype, file-extension

What is the difference between the `.html` and `.xhtml` file extensions?

What is the benefit of using the `.xhtml` extension?

Why we are not using the `.xhtml` extension, is it just because of IE?

What about .xhtml extension with IE 8?

Is `.xhtml` supported in other browsers besides IE? If yes, then what benefit we will get when all browsers support the `.xhtml` extension. Will we stop using `.html`?

Why do we use the XHTML doctype, but save those files using the `.html` extension?

Comment: Have a look at http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml is you want to know more about sending content with XHTML doctypes as HTML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If served over HTTP, the file extension has no meaning. The only information that matters it the [`Content-Type` header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) where the [media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of the resource is specified.

But when served from a local filesystem, the media type is normally identified by the file extension.

## Edit

I think the reason for why the extension `.html` is used even if it’s XHTML is because XHTML is HTML just with XML syntax and everyone is used to `.html` for HTML documents. (Although most XHTML documents are actually served as HTML as the media type `text/html` denotes HTML no matter what the document type declaration says.)

But again: extensions are not necessary when requested over HTTP. In HTTP the `Content-Type` header field tells what media type the resource should be interpreted with. So in theory you could use whatever extension you want or even use no extension at all (useful when content negotiation is used).

Comment: However, the extension usually has an effect on the Content-Type.

Comment: @ms2ger: No, the file extension has absolutely no effect on Content-Type.

Comment: It "has an effect" in that servers often map extensions to Content-Types (e.g., via Apache's `AddType` directive or its `mime.types` file), but you're right that it doesn't change the file's content (that would indeed be quite odd).

Comment: @Wevah: You’re right, but the server works on the filesystem. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the extension which matches the MIME type:

- `.xhtml` is for `application/xhtml+xml` documents
- `.html` is for `text/html` documents

For instance, ePub3 requires `.xhtml`:

> It is strongly suggested that you use the .xhtml extension for all EPUB content documents. Browsers will not interpret HTML content as application/xhtml+xml without that extension.

**References**

- [HTML5 and HTML/XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XHTML)
- [Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents/Examples)
- [Create rich-layout publications in ePub3 with HTML5, CSS3, and MathML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-richlayoutepub/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

IE (including IE8) is the only (significant) browser that *doesn't* support XHTML served as `application/xhtml+xml` (corresponds to the `xht` or `xhtml` extensions).

Will everyone move to XHTML when IE supports it? Probably not. XML isn't easy to get right, especially if you have to incorporate user-supplied data, such as blog comments. (Though that might be solved with (X)HTML5 `<iframe sandbox>` before IE starts playing along.) However, I don't have a crystal ball, so we'll just have to wait and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody cares what the file is named, just what the MIME type it's been transferred with is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the xhtml extension is used for XHTML only, but it is rarely used, because the HTML-type you are using is defined in the DOCTYPE-element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer. Why has it been downvoted so much?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers doesn't rely (just) on page extension, but in MIME content-type. This way you can, for instance, to create a PHP page which serves a JPG image.