# Redirect .html to .xhtml

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I had some old links with .html extension. Now I have moved all my urls to .xhtml

I saw the redirection rules [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html), but unable to figure out how to achieve this. I'm using amazon s3 and hosting my blog there.

As we all know [Cool URLs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). I'm trying to redirect a few html pages which I have already posted on social media.

Comment: If you are using S3, there was no need to use the [`.xhtml` extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1969300/1695906).  S3 allows you to set `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml` when uploading the object and the extension can be `.html` without consequences.

Comment: You are correct, S3 redirection rules don't support suffix matching or suffix modification -- only *prefix* matching and modification.  How many files are we talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect a few html pages which I have already posted on social media.

Answer (score 1):

It you need this for "a few" pages, maybe this:

> If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured for website hosting, you can redirect requests for an object to another object in the same bucket or to an external URL. You set the redirect by adding the `x-amz-website-redirect-location`  property to the object metadata. The website then interprets the object as 301 redirect. To redirect a request to another object, you set the redirect location to the key of the target object. To redirect a request to an external URL, you set the redirect location to the URL that you want.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

In other words, you can redirect each page individually if you create an empty file at each URL you want to redirect, setting `x-amz-website-redirect-location` to the target key.